# How do I prevent angular from rending both views when switching routes with an ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, angular-strap

I'm using angularjs with angular strap, and I have an ng-view that acts as the main container for my views and get updated with each route change. The problem I have is that Angular is showing both views, I looked at this question ([how to prevent AngularJs from having old view and new view on dom when route changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895111/how-to-prevent-angularjs-from-having-old-view-and-new-view-on-dom-when-route-cha)), but it doesn't really answer my question of how to either prevent it, or apply nice animations to it, because right now it just shows the new one below the old for for a split second. I tried `ng-animate="fadeIn"`, `ng-animate="{enter: 'am-fade-and-scale', leave:'am-fade-and-scale'}"`, `ng-animate="{enter: 'fadeIn', leave:'fadeOut'}"` and `ng-animate="none"` and in all cases I didn't get any animation, and both were visible at the same time. My HTML is below.

```
<body id="body">
 <div snap-content style="background-color: white">
     <div class="nav-contain" ng-controller="SidebarController">
         <ng-include src="'js/pages/sidebar.html'"></ng-include>
     </div>
     <div class="contain" ng-view autoscroll="true" ng-animate="{enter: 'am-fade-and-scale', leave:'am-fade-and-scale'}"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

**Update**:

I did get the animations works, I should have put the animation name on the class. `<div class="contain am-fade-and-scale" ng-view autoscroll="true" ng-animate></div>`, but the problem still remains that it puts the new content below the old content. So you both sets of content at the same time.

Comment: Are you seeing the sidebar at the top and then the template?

Comment: Yes the sidebar appears as we expect it to, but the content that lives in the ng-view shows up with the old content on the top of the page, and the new content below it on the page for a split second, even with animations.

Comment: can you share the two templates? Best would be if you create a plunker